# Not able to get query results using Room persistence

Tags: android, android-room

I am developing an Android app using the Room persistence library. I have a User and a Car entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User(@NonNull int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity(tableName = "cars", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(parentColumns  = 
"id", childColumns = "userId", entity = User.class))
public class Car {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private int userId;
    private String brand;

    public Car(int userId, String brand) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

Also I have created a UserWithCar class as below:

```
public class UserWithCar {

    @Embedded(prefix = "user_")
    public User user;

    @Embedded(prefix = "car_")
    public Car car;
}
```

As you can see in the UserWithCar I use a prefix cause if I don't I get the following error:

> Multiple fields have the same columnName: id. Field names: user > id,
>   car > id.

I want to get all the UserWithCar using the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.userId")
List<UserWithCar> getUserWithCar();
```

Using this query I get the following error:

> The query returns some columns [id, name, id, userId, brand] which are
>   not use by com.roomdemo.data.models.UserWithCar. You can use
>   @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.
>   com.roomdemo.data.models.UserWithCar has some fields [user_id,
>   user_name, car_id, car_userId, car_brand] which are not returned by
>   the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you
>   can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning
>   by annotating the method with
>   @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by
>   the query: id, name, id, userId, brand. Fields in
>   com.foodtec.roomdemo.data.models.UserWithCar: user_id, user_name,
>   car_id, car_userId, car_brand.

Can I have some help? Thanks!

**Update** 
Using @Wizard help, I removed the prefix from the @Embeded and I added @ColumnInfo "uId" for the User's id and "cId for the Car's id in order to not have the same id field. By this way it works!

Comment: can you update your final answer @eliamyro

Comment: Note to other people. This error can occur when you set @Fts4 annotation on your entity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Columns returned by the query: id, name, id, userId, brand. Fields in
>   com.foodtec.roomdemo.data.models.UserWithCar: user_id, user_name,
>   car_id, car_userId, car_brand.

Error indicates that, columns returned by query is different from Pojo class. It should be the same. Alternatively you can map your Pojo variable to column name using `@ColumnInfo` annotation.

For example,

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
private int id;
```

This way, `id` will be mapped to `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I add the column info in order to map the pojo variables then  I get this error: Columns returned by the query: user_id, user_name, car_id, car_userId, car_brand. Fields in com.roomdemo.data.models.UserWithCar: user_user_id, user_user_name, car_car_id, car_car_userId, car_car_brand.

Comment: That is because, You've embedded the `User` with `@Embedded`. Which eventually attaching prefix to all the variables.

Comment: So, do you suggest to remove the @Embedded annotations and use type converters?

Comment: No. just Try removing prefix of `@Embeded`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.userId")
```

to specify the columns in the POJO class UserWithCar. The columns returned must match all the columns, and have the same column name as your POJO. You can use AS to change the column names in the query.

```
@Query("SELECT userId as userId , brand as brand FROM users JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.userId")
```

Alternatively, you can use @ColumnInfo to specify the column name mappings.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589298/22466577) fixed mine, fixes yours if there's any chance you're using **kapt** in a java project!!
Bro says :

> Changed in gradle from this: *kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"*
> to this: *annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"*